# Complete hiding of an option with argp library

Tags: c, linux, glibc

argp(part of C library) provides an flag **OPTION_HIDDEN** to hide an option.
But this hides the option only from command help message. User can know about it as follows.

If user enters an partially matching text for hidden long option and which is ambiguous to other option. argp prints below message which will expose the hidden option. Is there any way i can make it not visible here?

**Ex:**
Let say an command named '`samplecli`' has two options '`--OPT1`' & '`--OPT2`'
and '--OPT1' is marked hidden. it is not visible on samplecli `-h|--usage|--help|-?'` as expected.
But when user types something like '`samplecli --OPT`',
argp outputs:

```
 #  samplecli --OPT   
      samplecli: option '--OPT' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--OPT1' '--OPT2'
      Try 'samplecli --help' or 'samplecli --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Option-Flags.html):

```
OPTION_HIDDEN
  This option isn’t displayed in any help messages.
```

Since the `is ambiguous` is clearly part of help, you've shown that the above contract is violated, i.e. there is a bug, and you should file one in glibc [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: Thank you. Raised bug [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20359)